# Way of reusing loopback model

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have to implement reporting application that requires fetching data from existing ITS such as Jira.

I was able to login by extending StrongLoop's User model and calling REST API from JIRA.

Now, I want to share this codes by creating loopback component or something so that I could use this login method later on.

Please share your knowledge or best practice for creating loopback component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at writing a [model "mixin"](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+mixins), but without seeing your code it's hard to say exactly what that would look like. You might also just define an internal-only model that extends the built in `User` and then additional models that extend your new model and are actually implemented in the REST API.